# Can't apply for a job listing

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I keep getting:

> This cover letter is identical to another that you've sent for another
>   job. You should always customize each cover letter for the specific
>   job that you are applying to.

Even when I've changed my cover letter.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for letting us know, we are doing some maintenance at the moment. You should be able to do so now.